# UIView background image resize in proportion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a Background.png image with size of 200*100, and i set background image for a uiview as:

```
    UIView view= UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```

Now, I reset the frame UIView by:

```
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(50,100,400,200)];
```

I need to resize the background image in proportion of the uiview, but i have only one fixed size Background.png image. what shall i do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take your size accordingly

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIView view= UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:newImage];
```

Else take an imageview and set `contentMode`, If u dont want to tile images

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what your needs are, it might be simplest just to add a UIImageView as a subview of your view, and set its image, letting it handling the resizing for you.  Otherwise, you'll probably have some complex resizing and drawing code to write.